# Run silent install in different thread - searching for solution without busy waiting

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm building installer project which need to dowload many installation files from the internet (downlading operation executed in parallel) and than start installing the files one by one. 
The installing sequence is not important. When a file is complete to be downloaded it inserted into queue and I have other worker which taking from this queue files and install them one by one.
I implemented almost everything and I have a problem in the installation process.

I'm installing the downloaded files in silent mode wih the next method:

```
        private void Install()
        {
            var item = _installItems.Dequeue();

            item.ProgStage = ProgressStage.Install;
            RefreshPgBars();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
           //insert psi arguments and file name here  

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);//start installing
}
```

I calling this method with a background thread:

```
        Thread worker = new Thread(() => Install());
        worker.IsBackground = true;
        worker.Start();
        worker.Join();
```

It seems that the Join method is not know when the installation is finished  - the code is not delayed at all on `worker.Join();` line.

I tried to insert the next code at end of `Install()` method in order to solve it:

```
           while (installerProcess.HasExited == false)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

and it is solve it but the `Thread.Sleep()` is freezing my entire app and proivde terrible user experience.
I also found a solution which includs Task and "busy waiting" loop but I'm searching for a better solution (more efficient one).

BTW I'm working with .NET 4.

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to block/freeze, then don't call `worker.Join`. It's as simple as that. For a further solution, we'd need to know *why* you wanted to call `worker.Join`.

Comment: Damien, If I won`t use Worker.Join() I might get concurrent installations. You right, Join also freeze my app. How can I avoid from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start` will just start the process and will not wait for it to complete. Hence your thread is over as soon as you start the process. Assuming the installer process will exit after the installation is complete, you can modify code this way:

```
private void Install()
        {
            var item = _installItems.Dequeue();

            item.ProgStage = ProgressStage.Install;
            RefreshPgBars();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
           //insert psi arguments and file name here  

            Process installProc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);//start installing
            installProc.WaitForExit();
}
```

To guarantee sequential installs, make sure you `Dequeue()` from `_installItems` in one thread and run the install process from that thread only.. then `Dequeue()` again .. do it in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd look to moving the installer to something like [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).  This sounds like a complex installation scenario with [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is ideally suited.

Comment: Thanks for your commment (I might use it for my next project)

Comment: Microsoft themselves use WiX for (as far as I know) the majority of their own installers including the SQLServer family of products.  I've authored a number of installers using it myself and it's highly recommended.

Comment: It's also worth considering that it maybe quicker to re-write this installer in WiX now depending on how long it takes to get this problem ironed out.  There are a lot of tools out there to deal with many scenarios in WiX.

Comment: My project is 90% implemented so from here I have just one direction to go :-)